# What does promising in (promising scholars) mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does *promising* mean in the phrase *promising scholars*?

For example:

> Doctoral Scholarship recipients are among **our most promising scholars**.

Answer (score 2):

*most promising* is used to show that they are very likely to be successful in the future.

Online site of Oxford Dictionaries describe -

> [promising (adj)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promising?q=promising) - showing signs of future success.

This means the doctoral scholarship recipients are the scholars with all signs of future success